# Changing .textcontent to display an image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a site that I'm making and I'm trying to make `editButton.textContent = 'Edit';` to instead of displaying text, display an image.

```
var editButton = document.createElement('button');
editButton.textContent = 'Edit';
```

I searched a few online tutorials, but none of them helped.

How would I do this?

Comment: Considering that an image isn't text, you'll likely need to create and append the img element, then set its attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `textContent`, that just displays plain text. Create an image element and put it in the button.

```
var editButton = document.createElement('button');
var editImage = document.createElement('img');
editImage.src = "URL for image";
editImage.alt = "Edit";
editButton.appendChild(editImage);
```